# Does C++14 and above allow default parameters for Lambda functions? If so how?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14, default-arguments

Does lambda functions changes to accept default arguments in c++ 14?

This example doesn't work on C++ 11:

```
int main() {

    int i = 34;
    auto RectSurf = [i](int length = 0, int width = 0){ return length * width;};
    cout << RectSurf(10) << endl;


    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

But it works fine on C++ 14 and above. So is it correct or not? Because C++ prime 5ed said that: "Passing Arguments to a Lambda
As with an ordinary function call, the arguments in a call to a lambda are used to initialize the lambda’s parameters. As usual, the argument and parameter types must match. Unlike ordinary functions, a lambda may not have default arguments (§ 6.5.1, p. 236). Therefore, a call to a lambda always has as many arguments as the lambda has parameters. Once the parameters are initialized, the function body executes.

As an example of a lambda that takes arguments, we can write a lambda that behaves like our isShorter function:" From C++ Prime 5ed.

But the same code on C++14 and above works fine! But Also I've read here in S.O That lambda functions can have a default parameter on condition that no variable has been captured in Lambda's capture list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Default Arguments in Lambda Expressions were explicitly added to the Standard with C++14, and were not permitted in C++11. You can see this if you [run the code against two different compiler flags in GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/3niZ6H), one for C++11, one for C++14, and compile using the `-Wpedantic` flag, you'll see that when compiled for C++11, the compiler issues a warning (GCC still supports it, but tells you it's not standard-compliant) whereas in C++14, there's no warning.

So yes. In C++14 and later, Default Arguments in a Lambda Expression are valid.

Comment: Ok Thanks. So you mean They've been added without any condition, I mean (like I've already said in my topic: Whether or not an object has been captured in capture list)?

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa I can't find any language in the standard stipulating that capturing variables ever influenced whether they were allowed to have default parameters or not. It's possible that was a compiler-specific restriction in your environment or the environment of whomever told you that was a thing.